# Refresh LWC component on another lightning page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I have a LWC component on Account page, which displays a few fields from related opportunity. The requirement states that I need to update LWC on the account record page whenever a defined set of fields are updated on the Opportunity record, without having to click on refresh button manually on the Account page.

I tried implementing `LMS` but the documentation suggests that it works when 2 components are on the same lightning page. Is there any other `pubsub` model which can be used to achieve this, without the help of apex? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use apex to fire an emp API event which will be handled by the LWC.

The other way around -

1. The polling mechanism will get fresh record values after brief time intervals.
   The problem with polling is that it will continue in the background even if you don't need the updated data so you need to stop it in disconnedtedCallBack.
2. Create a child component which has the opportunity record Id fetched in connecteCallBack of the parent component using Account record Id.
   Now, you need to update the Account record whenever the Opportunity gets updated through process builder/flow/trigger.
   Use the wire service in LWC with the LastModifiedDate field which will always change whenever you update the Account and be sure that the LastModifiedDate field is on the page layout it will trigger the wire service of the parent component now from there just re-assign the opportunity record Id to the API variable. For ex -

```
let oldRecId = this.opptyRecordId;
this.opptyRecordId ='';
this.opptyRecordId = oldRecId;
```

This will trigger the wire service of the child component as the parameter is changed and you can get the updated values.

Hopefully this will help you out.